Could Pg function/procedure invokings be automatically logged?
I have a list of Pg functions. I want to write a log while each of them being invoked. I create a table
call_logs(id serial,fn text,time timestsamp). 

I want to log each invoking automatically, that's to say, I don't want to embed a statement in each function to insert record into the call_logs table. Is there any mechanism to trigger a logger function with caller, callee as parameters when the functions in my list are called?

I don't think you can do that in PostgreSQL. For example, when the function causes an error, the log entry would be rolled back too.
